# Recommended size of the system partition?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning

I keep reading about the recommended boot partition size, but nothing about the system partition size. I'm asking for FAT32, exFAT and NTFS system partitions that is. Concerning both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.

I see people recommending 512MB and I see sometimes in screenshots people using 1GB. What is the reason behind these decisions? Why can't I make it 24MB for example.

Example taken from https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/faq/en_US/How-to-useWinToUSB-Physical-To-USB.html, quote:

> The system partition must be FAT32 format and the boot partition must
>   be NTFS format.

Another:

> The destination system partition must be a NTFS/FAT32 partition. If
>   the destination system partition is a FAT32 partition, then it must be
>   greater than or equal to 40 MB and less than or equal to 32 GB. (The
>   recommended size is 100 - 500 MB.)

Comment: There's no such thing as "FAT32, exFAT and GPS system partitions". Do you mean the EFI system partition?

Comment: Windows cannot be installed on exFAT.  I don’t even think Windows 10 will install as FAT32.  Your question is confusing and shows a severe lack of research effort

Comment: @Ramhound I'm talking(and asking) about the *system partition*, not the boot partition (the boot partition for Windows is of course NFTS format).

Comment: I am also talking about the system partition.  Windows 10 to my knowledge only can be installed on a partition system which uses NTFS and only reads FAT32 and exFAT partitions

Comment: @grawity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_partition_and_boot_partition

Comment: Neither of are talking about the boot partition, and your question still isn’t clear due to word “GPS” focus on improving your question instead of trying to correct us.

Comment: @Ramhound Nah, you can use FAT32 -> https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/faq/en_US/How-to-use-WinToUSB-Physical-To-USB.html, quote; "The system partition must be FAT32 format and the boot partition must be NTFS format."

Comment: You do understand that GPT isn’t a file system, right?  The EFI partition is FAT32.  Why would you want a 24 MB partition?

Comment: Are you asking the reason the EFI partition can’t be smaller then 40 MB?

Comment: @Ramhound Ah I see what you are saying. Yes MBR/GPT are partitioning types and then the rest are file systems. I was meaning between the different file systems, my bad!

Comment: @Ramhound That is one way you could put it :) Less than 40MB there, however I keep reading different numbers everywhere. Does the system partition need more space after the initial install? Does it grow? Is it the same for Linux as for Windows! So many questions :)

Comment: It grows only if you put additional EFI drivers on the partition.  Linux and Windows call the partition something else and this the requirements are different